# What is the advantage of top-down mergesort?

Tags: sorting

It seems like the divide step of recursive mergesort seems unnecessary. A bottom-up implementation that begins by splitting an array into a bunch of pairs and merging directly from there seems like it would always be preferable to dividing and merging recursively, as it would skip the splitting steps.

Is there any reason why top-down mergesort would be use and why it would be preferable / easier to implement than a bottom-up mergesort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both are optimized and basic (not hybrid) versions of merge sort, there is a question if the size of an array is not a power of 2, then top down does better splits, but top down doesn't begin any merging until the recursive splitting produces two runs of size 1, so no gain there, and an imbalance in the size of sub-arrays doesn't affect overall performance as much as the overhead of recursively splitting the array and storing all those indexes on the stack. There's also the question of cache locality: for top down merge sort, when sub-array size is small enough, merged (output) data will still be in the cache and available as input for the next merge operation, but at the same time that merged data cache is also being accessed to flush it out to main memory.

The overhead of recursion for top down has time complexity O(log2(n)), while the total sort time complexity for both top down and bottom up merge sort is O(n log2(n)), so as the array size gets larger, the relative overhead of top down diminishes, as most of the time will be spent merging sub-arrays.

In all my benchmark tests, bottom up is always faster than top down, but by a relatively small amount for large arrays. On my system (Intel 3770K 3.5 ghz, Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Visual Studio 2015), for 16 million 64 bit unsigned integers, bottom up takes about 1.5 seconds, top down about 1.6 seconds.

Most actual libraries use some variation of bottom up merge sort, usually a hybrid combination of insertion sort for small sub-arrays (16 to 64 elements) and bottom up merge sort, such as TimSort. The size of the sub-array to use with insertion sort is chosen so that it takes an even number of mergesort passes, with the sorted data ending up in the original array.

This leaves top down merge sort as mostly a learning exercise, especially if it's being taught along with quicksort, which is also top down.